# doxygen \code tag breaks html tags on the same page

Tags: doxygen

this is my first question ever here.

I have a strange problem when I use doxygen for documenting my C++ code. As soon as I have a \code tag on a page all html tags are not processed in the output.

The first example shows what I expected from the html tags. In the second example I just add a doxygen \code tag and the complete output is corrupt.

Example 1:

```
//!   \page testpage Test Page
//!
//!   <ul>
//!     <li>\ref test_section1</li>
//!     <li>\ref test_section2</li>
//!   </ul>
//!
//!   \section test_section1 Test Section 1
//!
//!   Any text.
//!
//!   \section test_section2 Test Section 2
//!
//!   Any text.
//!   <br><br>
```

[doxygen result of the first example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw4kK.png)

Example 2:

```
//!   \page testpage Test Page
//!
//!   <ul>
//!     <li>\ref test_section1</li>
//!     <li>\ref test_section2</li>
//!   </ul>
//!
//!   \section test_section1 Test Section 1
//!
//!   Any text.
//!
//!   \code
//!   if (x==1) return;
//!   \endcode
//!
//!   \section test_section2 Test Section 2
//!
//!   Any text.
//!   <br><br>
```

[doxygen result of the second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPnlK.png)

By the way I'm using doxygen 1.8.5 on linux.

Comment: What does happen with the current version (1.8.12) ?

Comment: Please don't use references to external sources / images as they might disappear over time. Place the image inside the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the current version of doxygen (1.8.12) solves the problem.

A better result in 1.8.5 can be obtained by disabling the Markdown support (MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = NO) in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile).

A good result can be also be obtained by using the following form of the code:

```
    /**
   \page testpage2 Test2 Page

   <ul>
     <li>\ref test_section1</li>
     <li>\ref test_section2</li>
   </ul>

   \section test_section1 Test Section 1

   Any text.

   \code
   if (x==1) return;
   \endcode

   \section test_section2 Test Section 2

   Any text.
   <br><br>
*/
```

and this goes independent of the setting of MARKDOWN_SUPPORT.

Advise is anyway use the current version (1.8.12).

Comment: It is a company computer where I have no root rights to update any program. Moreover it is opensuse 13.1 and it seems that there is no actual package for this distro.

Comment: When I set MARKDOWN_SUPPORT = NO the result looks much better. The only problem is that in front of each code line still a asterisk appear. But using C comment instead of C++ comment makes the result as I expected (independent of the setting of MARKDOWN_SUPPORT). So your answer is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Note that doxygen also has a `\tableofcontents` command, so you don't need to create one manually.